# Can't seem to get string from simpleXMLobject

Tags: php, xml, object

I have my xml file

```
<names>
    <person>
        <name>John</name>
        <alias>
            <part>Joe</part>
            <part>Foo</part>
        </alias>
    </person>
</names>
```

which I saved as `$xml`.

```
foreach($xml as $person)
    var_dump($person->name);
```

The above code returns

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (1) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "John"
}
```

instead of just

```
string(4) "John"
```

With the actual return it gives, I would assume adding `[0]` to the end of the variable would give me the correct return, but it returns the *exact same thing*.  I have tried adding `[0]`, `["0"]`, `->0`, `->"0"`, and nothing works.  The last 2 tries gave me a parse error, while the first 2 gave me the same response as the original.

How can I get the `string(4) "John"` from inside the `object(SimpleXMLElement)`?

Comment: By explicitly casting it to a string: `var_dump((string) $person->name);`

Comment: `$person->name->__toString()` But you can't to be afraid of this, php cast it to string. for exampe test `echo $person->name`

Comment: What @MarkBaker said. Or simply `echo`-ing or `print`-ing it, where the magic method `__toString()` is being invoked. https://3v4l.org/lrPMr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the XML is a resource, ie:

```
$xml = '<names>
        <person>
            <name>John</name>
            <alias>
                <part>Joe</part>
                <part>Foo</part>
            </alias>
        </person>
    </names>';

$parsed = simplexml_load_string($xml);

var_dump($parsed->getName());
```

Will output `names`, showing, that the element/layer you are in is named `names`.

And so will parsed->person->name give you a resource. If you want to drop the resource and just access the value, you need to convert it to string:

```
var_dump((string)$parsed->person->name);
```